# Problem with table view in iPhone when adding image to it

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

i have following code  to create cell and add image to it

```
UIImageView* MyImage =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,10,40,40)];  
[MyImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];  
[MyImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];  
[cell addSubview:MyImage];  
[MyImage release];  

cell.textLabel.text=[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
     return cell;
```

I am using this table for many purposes and therefore refreshing it again and again....
Therefore next i age overlaps the last one due to which problem occurs and both of these images are visible(i am using transparent background for each image)....  other problem occurs when i need no image..here i am unable to remove the last image ...

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you might be aware that when you reuse cell from 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier', it returns you existing cell instance if present, that means if cell exist its data also exists i.e. image, so you need to clear the old image before updating the cell with new data as if new data doesn't have image then it will show old image, I guess you got the point...

Ok here is the solution:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if(cell==nil)
{
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

   UIImageView* MyImage =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,10,40,40)]; 
   MyImage.tag = 1000; 

   [MyImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];  
   [cell addSubview:MyImage];  
   [MyImage release]; 
}
UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
imgView.image = nil;
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: UIImageView *imgView = [cell ViewWithTag:1000];
this line gives error          error is ==cell may not respond to viewWithtag

Comment: oh its 'viewWithTag' not 'ViewWithTag',

Comment: sorry but my program still crshes
i used all your code with return cell; added to it but it crashed again have you tried it?

Comment: @Sanniv it also not work with [MyImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];because old image also display with this.

Comment: @Ranjeet this can be work with [MyImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; change this line to [MyImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];it will help you

Comment: @Ranjeet, there can be many possible reason for crash in your program, if can put reason of crash (which you get from Console of Xcode) here then it will be helpful to debug....

Answer (score 0):

Where you use

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];
    }

Modify this to
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];

This one is the solution it always add new frame to old existing cell.

Or

Remove background color to some color from clear color and each time add on image either default image or particular image.same for label when you dont want to add any text to label then also add text=@"";

Comment: Hey Ishu, its wrong way to manage cell's content, if you consider proper memory management, Do you understand what dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier exactly does?, it avoids unwanted cell allocation.. and at the same time you get existing cell instance to update the content, then why are you allocating cell again, it will turn up in memory leak as well.

Comment: @Ranjeet I konow these solution , definately there mat be other solution exist.

Comment: @Sanniv, you are right this is not the right way.(It is a poor solution but this may be a solution).And also i propose one other solution.That will also work.